# How do i display linux command result in html

Tags: java, linux, html, email

I want to run linux command(ps aux --sort -rss | head -n 10) and display the result in table format in mail.
can somebody please suggest.
here is my script.

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh
current_dir=$(pwd)
script_dir=$(dirname $0)
if [ $script_dir = '.' ]; then
 script_dir="$current_dir"
fi

source_dir=$PWD
cd $script_dir
FWK_TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S`
REPORT_TS=`date -d '1 day ago' +'%m/%d/%Y'`
TILL_DATE=`date +%m/%d/%Y`

#javac -classpath mail1.4.4.jar:activation.jar SendEmail.java
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
 echo javac failed $?
 exit 1
fi

outfile=test.txt
rm test.txt
echo "<h1> Top 10 Memory Consumed Processes from $REPORT_TS  to $TILL_DATE</h1>" >> $outfile

ps aux --sort -rss | head -n 10 >> $outfile

to='abc@abc.com'
mail_server='-mail.smtp.host abc.com'
param="-to $to $mail_server -from abc@abc.com"

#-mail.debug
java -cp mail1.4.4.jar:activation.jar:. SendEmail $param -subject "Top Memory Consumed Processes" -file test.txt
```

Comment: Well, crudely, you could just write `<pre>` before the command output, and `</pre>`  afterwards. The browser would typically interpret the command output as pre-formatted, and respect the original white-space and line breaks. If you want to make a neat job, however, you'll need to split the output into lines, break each line into tokens, and write the tokens interspersed with the appropriate HTML tags.

Comment: thank you for suggestion and please advice on below please.
I am trying to write below result in file but it is not working.

case1:echo "<h5>" $result | awk -F'@' '{print $2}'  "</h5>" >> $outfile
case2: name=$result | awk -F'@' '{print $2}'
            echo "<h5>" $name"</h5>" >> $outfile

both cases not working

Answer (score -1):

As I am able to see in your code,
you are saving the results of
`ps aux --sort -rss | head -n 10 >> $outfile`
in the `$outfile`.

You can use `<iframe src="your_filename_goes_here" width=200 height=400 frameborder=0 ></iframe>`